# Solr / Lucene / Search Hosting

Tags: search, solr, lucene

I need some sort of hosted search API for my website where I can submit content and search content with fuzzy logic, where spelling mistakes and grammar won't affect results.

I want to use solr/lucene or whatever technology is out there, without needing to install stuff on my server to reduce setup complexity.

What solr/lucene/othersearch hosting services are there?

I'm read some other posts on stackoverflow, but they are either no longer in business or are wordpress extensions that require server installation (i.e. the processing is done on the server).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might consider [Websolr](http://websolr.com/), of which I am a cofounder, which is exactly the sort of service that you describe.

Answer (score 1):

The thing is, Solr is highly dependant on its datamodel. Or rather how your users search will really affect the way you structure the data model in Solr. As far as I know there aren’t any really good hosting services for Solr yet because you almost always need to do such extensive modifications to the Solr configuration (most notably the schema.xml).

However, with that said, Solr is really easy to get up and running. The example application is bundled with Jetty and runs more or less directly after download.

So unless you have immense scaling issues (read 5-10+ milj documents or a really high query per second load) I’d recommend you to actually install the application on your own server.

Comment: No where near, only have a few hundred documents and maybe 10,000 queries per day. Is it a good idea to install it on a web server? I'm running a VPS with 2GB RAM and 4 CPU cores, but just wondering if this is going to cause issues with MySQL, Apache and PHP etc.

Comment: Well you might need around 500+ Mb of RAM, maybe more depending on how complex your datamodel will be. Its genereally a good idea to keep the access to Solr locked down since you use the same port for quering as delets/admin. But no, Solr is just a java application hosted in a web container. There should be no conflicts with PHP/MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon CloudSearch is the best alternate if you do not want to worry about hosting.
http://aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/
http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/cloudsearch/latest/developerguide/SvcIntro.html

Comment: Perhaps you could provide links to the relevant AWS documentation in your answer?

Comment: so you do not consider cloudsearch link on AWS is a relevant link? http://aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/. It has all the docs, tutorial and how to use it, including pricing.

Answer (score 0):

gotosolr - http://gotosolr.com/en

- Apache Solr indexes are distributed on 2 hosting companies.
- Security is managed by Https and basic http authentication.
- Real-time statistics.
- Also ready for agencies with multi-accounts       and
  multi-subscriptions.
- Supports Drupal and WPSOLR (https://wordpress.org/plugins/wpsolr-search-engine/)